# Using Following-sibling in Xpath with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the year from the html below (https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/indian-premier-league-2022-1298423/punjab-kings-vs-delhi-capitals-64th-match-1304110/full-scorecard). Due to the way the site is coded I have to first identify the table cell that contains the word "Season" then get the year (2022 in this example).

I thought this would get it but it doesn't. There are no errors, just no results. I've not used the `following-sibling` approach before so I'd be grateful if someone could point out where I've messed up.

```
l.add_xpath(
            'Season',
            "//td[contains(text(),'Season')]/following-sibling::td[1]/a/text()")
```

html:

```
<tr class="ds-border-b ds-border-line">
    <td class="ds-min-w-max ds-border-r ds-border-line">
        <span class="ds-text-tight-s ds-font-medium">Season</span>
    </td>
    <td class="ds-min-w-max">
        <span class="ds-inline-flex ds-items-center ds-leading-none">
            <a href="https://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/series/index.html?season2022" class="ds-text-ui-typo ds-underline ds-underline-offset-4 ds-decoration-ui-stroke hover:ds-text-ui-typo-primary hover:ds-decoration-ui-stroke-primary ds-block">
                <span class="ds-text-tight-s ds-font-medium">2022</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
//span[contains(text(),"Season")]/../following-sibling::td/span/a/span/text()
```

Comment: Thanks @F.Hoque however there is a lot of different content with a similar path. That's why I tried using contains

Comment: @ Andy, I've updated and proven  following your url that will select text value : 2022 only